# SVN filtering commits by messages

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

I have to accept or not accept the commit on a particular repository based on the comments with the commit (using hooks). I don't know how to do it. I have to do it on a Windows device.  I read somewhere that I should modify the pre-commit.tmpl file to accept just that word as the commit so I did modify this statement:

```
SVNLOOK=/usr/local/bin/svnlook
$SVNLOOK log -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | \
    grep ""[a-zA-Z0-9]"" > /dev/null || exit 1
```

into this:

```
SVNLOOK=/usr/local/bin/svnlook
$SVNLOOK log -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | \
    grep "^.*hello.*$" > /dev/null || exit 1
```

Also, it says to change the .tmpl extension for windows. But I don't know if a grep search is right also, what is the other alternative to doing the same task?

Answer (score 1):

The exampels inside the .tmpl files are made for unix and using unix commands. You need to install the appropriate unix tools and adapt the scripts to your architecture(modifying paths etc..)

On windows you also need to **rename** the file to **.bat** so it is executable.

Note that no environment variables are available in hook scripts.

I would recommend to use python as a platform independent way of providing hook scripts. There are tons of python hook scripts available.

Comment: easy grepping *can* be replaced by findstr